# Saving the inputted data in a table for the next time I run my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm dieting and was bored so wrote a program (w my limited python knowledge) that loaded in a table from excel with 2 rows: each day's date since January and the calories I've eaten on each day. Then it asks for input: today's date, and how many calories I've eaten today, and puts this data into the table. Then it calculates my average caloric intake across the dates and how much weight I've lost.

I realized though that this only works for one day, today. Unless I go back and upload in a new table every day, the program runs based on the table that stops at yesterday, March 6th. How do I store the values that I input into the table for each time that I run it? Thanks.

Comment: Look into pandas dataframes to read and write(append) excel files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.